# Structural normalization algorithm for the simply typed lambda calculus

Tags: reference-request, type-theory, lambda-calculus

I would like to know if there is a (piecewise) structural normalization algorithm for the simply typed lambda calculus. By structural I mean a recursive function that only calls itself on subterms of its argument.

Suppose $T$ is an inductive type of terms, then it doesn't seem like there should be any way to define such a function $\text{nf} :T\to T$ directly, so what I want to know is whether one could define an intermediate inductive type $E$ and structural functions $p : T\to E$ and $r:E\to T$ so that $r\circ p:T\to T$ is the normalization function.

The motivation for this is that proving termination is immediate from the well-foundedness of the inductive types.

Are there any other references or implementations that address this question?

Comment: Do you consider $M[N/x]$ to be a subterm of $(\lambda x.M)N$?

Comment: @MartinBerger If you choose a tree representation for terms, then a subterm is a subtree, so I would not consider this a subterm unless you have some very clever encoding of terms.

Comment: This is a core feature of "normalization by evaluation" (nbe). There are lots of references for nbe.

Answer (score 1):

You can: define /hereditary substitution/ on already normalized STLC terms using structural induction (where the induction is (in part) on the type).

I couldn't find the reference I was thinking of right now, but a quick search for "agda hereditary subtitutions STLC" pointed to various relevant pages, such as https://github.com/ezyang/lr-agda/blob/master/STLC.agda